# MySQL and PHP - using 'LIKE' AND 'NOT LIKE'

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-like

I need some help with using LIKE and NOT LIKE together... I have a query that I pass WHERE clauses through based on what my request variable is from another server. One of the queries is like the following:

```
    'CONNECT' =>
    "( detail_head.comment LIKE '%port%'
      or detail_head.comment LIKE '%forward%'
      or detail_head.comment LIKE '%connect%'
      or detail_head.comment LIKE '%router%'
      or detail_head.comment LIKE '%fire%wall%'
      or detail_head.comment LIKE '%sonic%'
      ) AND (
      detail_head.comment NOT LIKE '%report%'
      OR detail_head.comment NOT LIKE '%portal%'
      )",
```

You can see that I am using LIKE and NOT LIKE. This unfortunately does not work the way I hoped it would. I am guessing it's because I am asking for PORT, but not REPORT, so it gives me the LIKE regardless.

I was wondering what I should do in a case like this. I was thinking about making another query or array that I would use as an 'exclude list'. Where the queries would be LIKE statements, that I could use in my WHERE clause to say 'table_uid NOT IN(LIST OF COMMA SEPARATED UIDs)'.

I have my LIKE statements that I'd like to exclude:

```
$exclude_where_clauses = array(
        'CC'            => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%ccb%') ",
        'CONNECT'       => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%report%' OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%portal%') ",
        'EO'            => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%OCU%' AND detail_head.comment LIKE '%KS%' AND detail_head.comment LIKE '%screen%' AND detail_head.comment LIKE '%term%') ",
        'INVENTORY'     => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%discount%') ",
        'KS'            => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%panel%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%PMIX%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%pmix%') ",
        'OCUS'          => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%document%') ",
        'SALES'         => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%point%') ",
        'SECURITY'      => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%km%') ",
        'TERMS'         => "(detail_head.comment LIKE '%forward%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%sales%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%intermittent%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%print%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%de%min%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%reciept%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%time%') ",
);
```

So, in the end, I'd like to be converting my current array of queries to say `"(detail_head.comment LIKE '%port%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%forward%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%connect%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%router%'  or detail_head.comment LIKE '%fire%wall%' or detail_head.comment LIKE '%sonic%') AND table_uid NOT IN(LIST OF COMMA SEPARATED UIDs) "`

Comment: Please post an example comment, too, so we can see "report" and "port" in context.

Comment: Also note, I think I have most of what I wanted to do coded out... I'm just not sure how it will work:

Comment: $exclude_where_clause = $exclude_where_clauses[$_REQUEST['count_request']];
$not_like_qry = "SELECT detail_head.scr FROM detail_head WHERE detail_head.call_status != 'c' AND call_origins_uid != 5 AND $exclude_where_clause ";
$qry .= "AND call_origins_uid != 5 GROUP BY detail_head.scr ";
$dob->setQuery($not_like_qry);
while ($dob->fetch(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $dob->getRowAsArray();
}
foreach ($rows as $row) {
        fputcsv($tmpdata, $row, '|');
}

Comment: Beware of the performance implications of using `LIKE '%keyword%'`. Using `LIKE` in this way can seriously slow down your queries, especially if you have a large amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'CONNECT' => "
    (  detail_head.comment LIKE '%port%'
    OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%forward%'
    OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%connect%'
    OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%router%'
    OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%fire%wall%'
    OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%sonic%'
    )
    AND NOT (
           detail_head.comment LIKE '%ccb%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%report%' 
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%portal%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%OCU%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%KS%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%screen%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%term%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%discount%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%panel%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%PMIX%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%pmix%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%document%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%point%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%km%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%forward%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%sales%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%intermittent%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%print%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%de%min%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%reciept%'
        OR detail_head.comment LIKE '%time%'
    )
",
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this will be any more efficient (it may indeed be less efficient), but, it may be a way to define your specifications more soundly -- using word boundaries in a `regexp()`.

This returns 0:

```
SELECT 'foo report bar' REGEXP '[[:<:]]port[[:>:]]';
```

Where this returns 1:

```
SELECT 'foo report bar' REGEXP '[[:<:]]report[[:>:]]';
```

[MySQL has more info in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). (5.1 manual linked)

Depending on the nature of the task at hand, and how regularly and how much strain this will put on my database server, I might consider adding fields or a related table to help me do the processing up front (when I insert the data) so I can run reports like this after the fact in a lighter fashion -- instead of having to do heavy textual processing in fulltext fields.